# Show $\frac{du}{dx}=|u| \ (x\in\mathbb{R}$) has solutions $u=Ae^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

> Show the following ODE has solutions of the form $u=Ae^x$: $$\frac{du}{dx}=|u|, \ x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

My attempt:

I first considered the case where $u>0$.
So, \begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx}&=u \\
\int \frac{du}{u}&=\int dx \\
\ln|u|&=x+C, \ \ C\in\mathbb{R} \\
u&=Ae^x, \ \ A=e^c\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align}
Next, for the case where $u<0$ (using separations of variables as above), I get that,
$$u=Ae^{-x}.$$
For the final case, $u=0$,
$$u=0.$$
Only one of these cases admits the required form. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong, you are right here. I would have thought that in this form question asks you to verify if these functions are solutions of this DE, not to show that all solutions are of this form (which is clearly not true).

Comment: Is each case of the form required? I does not appear that way.

Comment: @Evgeny Why is the $Ae^{-x}$ right?

Comment: @JackBauer It is right when $A < 0$: the derivative would be $-Ae^{-x}$ and $\vert A e ^{-x} \vert = -A e^{-x}$ when $A < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $u>0$ and $u<0$ are not both possible. Either $u>0$ everywhere or $u<0$ everywhere. Here is the argument: consider the open set $U=\{x: u(x)>0\}$.  On this set we have $u(x)=Ae^{x}$. Clearly $A >0$. Let us show that the open set $U$ has no boundary point. If there is a boundary point $x$ then there is a sequence $x_n \in U$ converging to $x$. We then have $u(x) =0$ and $u(x)=\lim u(x_n)$ so $Ae^{x_n} \to 0$, hence $e^{x_n} \to 0$, But this is possible only when $x_n \to -\infty$ contradicting the fact that $x_n \to x$. This proves that $U$ is an open set with no boundary points. This implies that it is either empty or the whole line. Thus the cases $u>0$ and $u<0$ cannot both occur.

Comment: Why is the $Ae^{-x}$ right?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy is $u=0$ also a valid case?

Comment: When $A=0$ we get $u \equiv 0$. I have left this case to the OP.  Thanks to Jack Bauer for pointing out the silly mistake. I had typed $e^{-x}$ instead of $e^{x}$. I have corrected it now.

Comment: I think I understand. Is $u=0$ case just a special case of the other cases (just where $A=0$)? Hence the $u=0$ case still admits the required form.

Comment: Yes, $u=0$ can occur only when $A=0$.

Comment: I am having trouble visualizing the fact that $u<0$ and $u>0$ cannot both occur at the same time. Can this be explained using a graph of $t=|u|$?

Comment: You have to somehow match the two solutions $Ae^{x}$  valid for $u>0$ and $Ae^{-x}$  valid for $u<0$ so as to get one differentiable function defined on the whole of $\mathbb R$ which satisfies the given DE. Try taking $Ae^{x}$ and $e^{-x}$ in, say $(-\infty , c)$ and $(c,\infty)$ for example; you find that it is impossible to make the function continuous. That is the basic idea. Since we do not know what kind of open set $\{u>0\}$ is, we have to use some topology in the proof.

Comment: Okay thanks. I was hoping to avoid the use of topology, but there seems no way around it haha

Comment: Do you concur with the statements made by E-mu in the comments of Jack Bauer response?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $u$ solves the DE $u'(x)=|u(x)|$ on $\mathbb R.$ Some cases to consider:

1. If $u(x) >0$ on $\mathbb R,$ then $u(x) = Ae^x$ for some $A>0.$ Your proof works here.
2. If $u(x) <0$ on $\mathbb R,$ then $u(x) = Ae^{-x}$ for some $A<0.$

Proof: We have $u'(x)=|u(x)|= -u(x)$ in this case. Thus $u'(x)/u(x)\equiv -1.$ Integrating gives $\ln |u(x)| = -x+c,$ which implies $|u(x)|= e^{-x}e^c.$ Since $|u|=-u,$ we get $u=-e^ce^{-x}.$ Set $A=-e^c$ to see $u$ has the desired form.

3. $u\equiv 0.$ Not much to say here,  except that in this case $u$ has the form $Ae^x,$ with $A=0.$

Claim: If $u$ solves the DE, then one of 1,2,3 must hold.

Proof: Suppose $u$ is a solution and $u(a)=0$ for some $a.$ We will show $u\equiv 0.$

Suppose, to reach a contradiction, that $u(b)>0$ for some $b>a.$ Let $c$ be the largest number in $[a,b]$ such that $u(c)=0.$ Then $u$ is nonzero in $(c,b].$ By the IVT, $u>0$ or $u<0$ on $(c,b].$ Since $u(b)>0,$ we must have $u>0$ on this interval. So we have $u>0$ on $(c,b).$ Exactly as you showed in your proof of $1,$ we then have $u(x) = Ae^x$ in $(c,b)$ for some $A>0.$  It follows that $\lim_{x\to c^+}u(x)= Ae^c >0.$ But this limit also equals $u(c)=0$ by the continuity of $u$ at $c.$ This is a contradiction, proving there is no such $b.$

Similarly there is no $b<a$ at which $u$ is positive. Furthermore, using the same ideas, there is no $b\ne a$ at which $u$ is negative. Therefore $u\equiv 0.$

We have shown that if $u$ satisfies the DE and equals $0$ somewhere, it equals $0$ everywhere. By the IVT, any other solution to the DE satisfies either $u>0$ or $u<0$ everywhere, which lands us in cases 1 or 2 above.

There is one point above that needs mention: Why is there a largest $c$ in $[a,b]$ such that $u(c)=0?$ It is because the set $\{x: u(x)=0\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ by the continuity of $u.$ I can say more on this if you would like.

By the way, in a comment you said you were hoping to avoid any topology. But the MVT is embedded in the integration results we have used. We also used the IVT. The rigorous proofs of these results, often sidestepped in a first year calculus course, depend on basic topology as well.

Comment: Do you mind just expanding on your second paragraph please :)

Comment: Did you mean the second to last paragraph?

Comment: Yes please, sorry about that.

Comment: Let $E= \{x\in [a,b]: u(x) = 0\}.$ Define $c=\sup E.$ If we show $c\in E,$ we're done: $c$ is the largest number in $[a,b]$ such that $u(c)=0.$ Now for each $n$ there exists $x_n\in E$ such that $c-1/n<x_n\le c.$ We then have $x_n\to c,$ hence $u(x_n)\to u(c)$ by continuity. Since $u(x_n)=0$ for all $n,$ $u(c)=0.$ Thus $c\in E$ as desired.

Comment: I have a question. How is $u=Ae^{-x}$ of the form $u=Ae^{x}$? Isn't the former decreasing?

Comment: Also, is DE satisfied only when $u\neq 0$?

Comment: $Ae^{-x}$ is not of the form $Ae^x.$ It's not decreasing because $A<0$ in this case. Example: $-e^{-x},$ which is increasing. The only solution that allows $u=0$ somewhere is $u\equiv 0.$

Comment: I think I misunderstood. What exactly is the answer in short?

Comment: The solutions are $Ae^x,A>0,$  $Ae^{-x},A<0,$ and $u\equiv0.$

Comment: But these cannot occur at the same time right?

Answer (score -1):

$u=0$ is part of the first case for $u=Ae^x$ if you were to say $A \ge 0$. Your first case can actually be $A>0$ because you assumed $u>0$. For your second case you should get

$$\ln|u|=x+C$$

$$\implies \ln(-u)=x+C$$

$$\implies -u=Ae^x$$

$$\implies u=-Ae^x$$

for $A=e^C > 0$

Altogether we can merge the three cases to have $u(x)=Ae^x, x \in \mathbb R, A \in \mathbb R$ where $sgn(A)=sgn(u(x))$

Comment: No $u=0$ is not part of the first case. We need to assume $u\not =0$ to divide by $u$ and integrate. Thus this needs to be handled separately.

Comment: @Winther I said "if you were to say $A \ge 0$". Without the condition, $u=0$ may or may not be part of the first case.

Comment: That's my point: we are not allowed to take $A=0$ as the derivation is only valid if $A\not =0$.

Comment: @Winther If the assumption is false, then the implication is correct:P

Comment: I am confused now.

Comment: Is $A$ allowed to equal zero to concur with the required form?

Comment: For $u(x)<0,A<0$, $u=Ae^x$. For $u(x)>0,A>0$, $u=Ae^x$. For $u(x)=0,A=0$, $u=Ae^x$ because $0=u=Ae^x=0e^x=0$. So yes?

Comment: Isn't the differential equation $\frac{du}{dx} = -u$ in the case $u < 0$? Does that not imply $\text{ln}|u| = -x + C$?

Comment: @Jack Bauer  For A < 0 your proposed solution is strictly decreasing, whereas the differential equation indicates that the solution must be non decreasing.

Comment: @E-mu Ok then therefore we cannot have $A<0$ and hence $A \ge 0$ only?